# Simplifying $\sin(\sqrt{iz})/\sin(\sqrt{i\bar{z}})$

Tags: complex-analysis

How can I simplify $|\sin(\sqrt{iz})/\sin(\sqrt{i\bar{z}})|$, where $z$ is a complex number?

What I did so far:  let $\sqrt{iz}=u$, then $iz=u^2$, and $i\bar{z}=-\bar{u}^2$, so 
$\sqrt{i\bar{z}}=iu$ (I'm not sure about the last one!)

so: 
$\sin(\sqrt{iz})/\sin(\sqrt{i\bar{z}})=\sin(u)/\sin(iu)$

and now I can use the representation of $\sin(u)$ in terms of $e^{iu}$.

Anything wrong with the method above!

// I've been asked to simplify this expression, no mention for the branch!//

So, no help!

Comment: Have you tried using the identity $i\sin x = \dfrac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$?

Comment: What do you mean by $\sqrt{iz}$? Which branch of the square root are you concerned with?

Comment: @Willie: But, but ... when you take the absolute value, the choice of branch doesn't matter ... of course you should prove that!